# How to download a file from dropbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropbox

I have a pdf file stored in dropbox. I have an URL to access that pdf file. The format of the URL is something like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/myPDF.pdf.

Now I need to use this URL in my angular application to download that PDF file and show it's content.

I need to display the pdf in the same webpage as my application. I used  tag for achieving this. But I got the error saying **Refused to display the pdf in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAVEORIGIN'**.

I am new to dropbox. I need to know how to download this pdf and show it's content in my angular application by using the URL given above.

Comment: Just open `url` in new window. It will automatically download.

Comment: The modifications you can make to these links, documented here: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201 may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem buddy. You dont need javascript for this, it can be done with simple  and  "anchor" tags.

Write the code as follows:

```
<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/myPDF.pdf">
<button>Download pdf</button>
</a>
```

Now, when the user clicks the button, the file will be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to open the pdf in the current webpage. I tried using iframe tag. But it gave error     Error: $sce:insecurl
Processing of a Resource from Untrusted Source Blocked